# Backbone HTTP call before application starts

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, marionette

I want to send Authentication call like `/login` before backbone app starts and want to set current_user based on the response.

The problem I am facing is when I am sending ajax call in my main `project.js.coffee` before getting the response of authentication request controller's show method getting called and there I am not able to get current user. This is happening with every controller.

I have following code in my `project.js.coffe`

```
app = do (Backbone, Marionette) ->

  App = new Marionette.Application

  App.rootRoute = 'dashboard'
  App.Radio = Backbone.Radio
  App.canvasChannel = Backbone.Radio.channel('page-builder')    
  mainRegion = Marionette.Region.extend el: "#main-region"

  App.addRegions
    mainRegion: mainRegion
    modalRegion: '#modal-region'

  App.addInitializer ->
    App.module('Dashboard').start()

  App.on 'before:start', (options) ->
    # I want to send HTTP request here
    App.request('set:current:user', Project.current_user)
  $.extend(@Project, app)
```

Code of dashboard `controller.js.coffee`:

```
@Project.module 'Dashboard', (Dashboard, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  Dashboard.Controller =

    initialize: ->
      console.log("Inside initialize request");

    show: (tab, refresh = false, scrollTop = 0) ->
      # Here I want to get the current user
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you actually starting the application? (`app.start()`)

Can't you just start it after the request is successful?

Comment: @TJ I am not starting it manually. It’s backbone Lifecycle method App start which is running first time when app starts.

Comment: I have multiple routs in application I just want to do it before any of that routs gets called.

Comment: Backbone does not have anything such as "app life cycle". This is part of marionette, and you have to start a marionette app as far as I know. Maybe you are not aware of the code that starts the marionette app? Is the entire codebase written by you?

Comment: No entire codebase is not written by me that’s why I was assuming. @TJ Do we anything in marionette?

Comment: Right now I am making ajax call in every route controller method. I have written method in model and it’s getting called by every route. It’s working but I believe there will a better way to do this.

Comment: there's an example for [#Marionette.Application](https://marionettejs.com/docs/master/marionette.application.html#marionetteapplication) on the main site. In their example, of interest to you, note `loadInitialData`.